# Comparing string in bash scripting

Tags: string, bash, csv, conditional-statements

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r user store date amount
do
  if [[ "$user" != "User" ]]
    then
    {
      echo $user is different: User
    }
  fi
done <<EOF
User, Store, Date, Amount
User1, Store1, Date1, 100
User2, Store2, Date2, 200
EOF
```

Running script in debug mode:

```
bash -x script.sh
+ IFS=,
+ read -r user store date amount
+ [[ User != \U\s\e\r ]]
+ echo User is different: User
User is different: User
...
```

I have tried with single quotes, double quotes, single and double containers in the condition statement but it still it won't work. Would someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code posted here is fine, and though not relevant to the claimed problem here, be aware that the spaces in the CSV file are part of the fields they are adjacent to.

Comment: Works for me, only User1 and User2 are reported.

Comment: @kit Be careful when editing code. You changed whitespace, which in this case would have broken existing functionality: `{ echo 'string' }` requires a semicolon before `}`, as in `{ echo 'string'; }`; it's not required if `}` is on a new line, as it was originally.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks your advice ben~ I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Works for me - but I don't understand why you're using Bash and `[[` when plain POSIX shell and `[` will do the job much more cheaply.  And what's the reason for the sub-shell in the `then` clause?